# How to map afield of an object on a map

Tags: apex, query, map, related-list

I have a map for an object for which I want to use a name field on the object as a key and value  as map huishoudMap = new map

Is there something similar to map ?

How do I achieve this using map:

```
map<name,Huishouden__c> huishoudMap = new map<name,Huishouden__c>([
    SELECT Id,
        Name,
        (SELECT id, Huishouden__c FROM Relatie_Contacten__r)
    FROM Huishouden__c]);

for (Relatie__c rc: rcList) {
    string relKeyId = rc.Contactpersoon__r.MailingPostalCode + rc.Contactpersoon__r.MailingStreet + ' ' + rc.Account__r.Relatienummer__c;
    system.debug('rc.Huishouden__c '+rc.Huishouden__c);
    if (huishoudMap.containsKey(relKeyId)) {
        rc.Huishouden__c =  huishoudMap.get(relKeyId).id;
    } else {

    }
    update rcList;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apex you can construct only `Map<Id, sObject>` from SOQL query result.
If you want to get Name field as key, you would use `Map<String, sObject>`

Try

```
Map<String ,Huishouden__c> huishoudMap = new Map<String, Huishouden__c>();

for(Huishouden__c hs : [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT id, Huishouden__c FROM Relatie_Contacten__r) FROM Huishouden__c]) {
    huishoudMap.put(hs.Name, hs);
}
```

Comment: I have to disagree with you on your first sentence. You can use any type to build the map. Quoting the doc: "Map keys and values can be of any data type, including sObject types, such as Account." https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_map_sobject.htm

Comment: @POZ, please refer to paragraph **Auto-Populating Map Entries from a SOQL Query** from the same document. You can declare the Map as new Map<String, sObject>([SOQL]), but the key will be taken from Id field anyway.

Comment: @POZ I think there's some confusion in terminology here. When I hear "build a map", I think "insert data into the map". I'd call what you're talking about "declaring" a map. While it's true that a Map can use basically any type as the key, if you're using the Map constructor that takes a `List<SObject>`, like `Map<Id, SObject> myMap = new Map<Id, SObject>([<query here>]);` (as OP is trying), that will only work if the map key is an `Id`. There is a way around that using aggregate functions and field aliasing, but that approach has some drawbacks and I don't think it's worth the trouble.

Comment: Yes, true. I should have written 'construct' instead of 'build'. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are facing is that `Name` is not a type so you cannot use it in your `Map` declaration (line 1).

You should use a `String` instead:

```
Map<String,Huishouden__c> huishoudMap = new Map<String,Huishouden__c>();
for (Huishouden__c record: [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT id, Huishouden__c FROM Relatie_Contacten__r) FROM Huishouden__c]) {
    huishoudMap.put(record.Name, record);
}
```